# MySQL stored procedure claiming subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

If I execute this SQL:

```
SET @myId = (SELECT `MyId` from `LinkTable` where `LinkTableId` = '73548055');
SELECT * FROM `MyTable` AS `Extent1` WHERE  `Extent1`.`MyId` = @myId;
```

I get a single row.

If I put it in a stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE `Get_Results`(IN linkTableId nvarchar(255))
BEGIN


    SET @myId = (SELECT `MyId` from `LinkTable` where `LinkTableId` = linkTableId);
    SELECT * FROM `MyTable` AS `Extent1` WHERE  `Extent1`.`MyId` = @myId;

END

CALL `Get_Results`('73548055')
```

I get the error

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Why?

EDIT: For the sake of interest, I just tried changing the SP to

```
PROCEDURE `Get_Results`(IN linkTableId nvarchar(255))
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM `MyTable` AS `Extent1` WHERE  `Extent1`.`MyId` IN (SELECT `MyId` from `LinkTable` where `LinkTableId` = linkTableId);
END
```

And it *still* returns the same error.

Comment: @RaymondNijland But if you run it outside the SP, with the same parameter, it returns a single row.

Comment: do you have any nulls in your source?

Comment: @jimmy8ball There might be null fields. Shouldn't be any whole-row nulls

Comment: what about any null id's?

Comment: @jimmy8ball Nope. They're all keys.

Comment: ok, can you try the same code but add in a distinct into the In statement

Comment: @jimmy8ball You mean in the subquery? Done - still giving the same error. Totally baffled by this! Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure

```
SET @myId = (SELECT `MyId` from `LinkTable` where `LinkTableId` = myLinkTableId);
```

This sub query return only 1 row.

Comment: I have - that's what the code above intends to demonstrate.

Comment: @MattThrower, change Procedure parameter name **linkTableId** to **myLinkTableId**

Comment: Good spot, but that's not the problem in the original code.

Comment: Check here http://rextester.com/TUYNH75803

Comment: @MattThrower, for testing purpose you can add limit 1 in your sub query